# What does the word ''affinity'' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In this following context, which one of below-mentioned two meanings is campatible with the word ''affinity'' ?

Affinity

1. a strong feeling that you understand somebody/something and like them or it
2. a close relationship between two people or things that have similar qualities, structures or features
   (Oxford advanced Learner's dictionary)

Context:

> Whoso, devoid of compassion can kill men, or even animals, carries
> deep within himself the inclination to shorten life. He finds
> satisfaction, or even pleasure, in the short-livedness of other
> creatures. Short-lived germs have therefore some affinity for him, an
> affinity which makes itself known after his death in the grasping of
> another germ, which then takes place to his own detriment. Even so,
> germs bearing within themselves the power of developing into a
> deformed body, have an affinity for one who finds pleasure in
> ill-treating and disfiguring other.

Source:
https://tinyurl.com/yc47s6m5

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'germs' are that the author refers to - presumably not harmful bacteria! - but I think it must be definition 2.

Comment: @KateBunting - This is about the Buddhist theory of reincarnation. When you die, your soul or spirit attracts the 'germ' or seed of your next life. (old fashioned biological texts talk of 'germ cells'). If you did bad things in the life just ended, your soul is 'ugly' and attracts a bad germ which will confer upon you a short bad next life. These bad germs have an affinity or attraction for souls which are marred by wrongdoing or spiritual ugliness. Definition (2). Do bad stuff, be reborn as a disabled person, I think.